# Firebase querying data limitToLast

Tags: firebase

I am still working with previous API, however I just came across one little issue. I am trying to query data from Firebase based on the limitToLast(100), however the .val() of snapshot is always null.

Here is sample data structure of my Messaging:

```
“Messaging” :{
  "10153530036627802" : {
    "10155174395220402" : {
      "LastUpdate" : 1429295238531,
      "Messages" : {
        "1428338024339" : {
          "date" : 1428338024339,
          "message" : "Yo",
          "sender" : "Uksz"
        },
        "1428338024488" : {
          "date" : 1428338024487,
          "message" : "Yo",
          "sender" : "Uksz"
        },
        "1429023827304" : {
          "date" : 1429023827303,
          "message" : "Fygh",
          "sender" : "Uksz"
        },
        "1429023828469" : {
          "date" : 1429023828468,
          "message" : "Fygh",
          "sender" : "Uksz"
        },
        "1429295238532" : {
          "date" : 1429295238531,
          "message" : "Hgh",
          "sender" : "Uksz"
        }
      },
      "Name" : "Matt",
      "Picture" : "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/xxxx"
    },
NEXT_USER_ID
```

And my code is:

```
    var firebaseRef = new Firebase ("https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/Messages/");
    var messageRef = firebaseRef.child(userId).child(recipient).child("Messages");
    var messagesRef2 = messageRef.limitToLast(10);
    messagesRef2.on("value", function(snapshot){
      console.log(snapshot.val())
      })
```

Whenever I am getting snapshot.val(), its value is equal to null. Where did I go wrong?

Thanks,
Uksz

Comment: Your data example has `Messaging` as a root, but your code uses a path to `Messages`. Is this a mistake in your question? If not, it's probably the cause of your problem.

Comment: Now I feel like an idiot.. That was the issue :) Thanks so much!

Comment: Just a side note, the declaration, `var firebaseRef.child(userId).child(recipient).child("Messages");`, seems to be missing a variable name.

Comment: Oh ya, the code in the post was pasted in the wrong way :) thanks!

Comment: console.log(snapshot.val()) should have a semicolon...  console.log(snapshot.val());

Comment: you are using root as Messaging it should be https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/Messaging/